# Configure objectmapper inside Custom serializer jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

I have a CustomSerializer for a particular field written. I call the custom serializer on an `ObjectMapper` with certain configurations like `WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`, `PropertyNameStrategy`, `Inclusion.NON_NULL`.

Now inside my custom serializer I want all these properties while serializing my custom class except one (`WRAP_ROOT_VALUE`).

```
public class CustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object obj, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
//.......
        jgen.writeObject(obj);
//...       
    }
```

So my `obj` here gets serialized with root value wrapped which I don't want.

I cannot edit my POJO for some reason.

How can I disable only a single (or some) property of `Objectmapper` inside a CustomSerializer ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Getting the `ObjectMapper`

From within a custom [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html), you can get the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) using:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = ((ObjectMapper) jgen.getCodec());
```

### Setting the `ObjectMapper`

You also can define a new [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) within your custom [`JsonSerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonSerializer.html) using:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
jgen.setCodec(mapper);
```